# Как сделать рукопожатие websocket

Tags: c#, websocket

При попытке выполнить этот код:

```
using (var ws = new ClientWebSocket())
             {
                 await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://ws-gate.fxclub.org/ws"), CancellationToken.None);

                 Console.WriteLine(ws.State);

                 if (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                 {
                     //Мы подключились и можем отправлять данные.
                     Console.WriteLine("Подключился");

                    // ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SD"));
                    // await ws.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

                     ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
                     WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, CancellationToken.None);
                     var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count);
                     Console.WriteLine(response);
                 }
             }
```

На отправке сообщения, выдает ошибку, что рукопожатие было не завершено.
Я почитал что и как.
Теперь я отправляю get запрос на рукопожатие, мне его одобряет, что теперь дальше, как httpclient передать заголовки websocket? Или что ему нужно передать после рукопожатия?

Comment: А мне вот интересно, а зачем вы мучаетесь с сокетами, если там есть простой API, который все нужные данные отдает?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне нужно постоянный и быстрый поток данных, такое только через websocket можно добиться + я хочу изучить, как websocket работает в c#